# Is there a built-in/easy Jordan Canonical Form method in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I see the method to perform eigen-decomposition for Hermitian matrices, but could not find a method to perform Jordan Canonical Form. Can anyone suggest a function to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure numpy/scipy implementation (which the dupe doesn't give), I recommend simply doing something like:

```
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
def JordanForm(a, thr = 10**-5):
    data = np.zeros((2, a.shape[0]))
    data[0] = scipy.linalg.eigh(a)[0]
    data[1,:-1] = (np.diff(data[0]) < thr).astype(int)
    return dia_matrix((data, np.arange(2)), shape = a.shape)
```

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in the last line.  Should the return value be `dia_matrix((data, np.arange(2)), shape = a.shape)`?

Comment: This function does not correctly compute the Jordan normal form.  Try it with, say `a = np.eye(4)`.  It should return the same identity matrix, but instead it creates a Jordan block of size 3.